# Unable to connect with nodejs using proxy

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, proxy

I am using node.js for my chat application with https. It is working fine in all condition but the problem is with VPN.

I installed the turbo VPN into my android phone and connected to the proxy server. After this whenever I am going to connect to the chat server it fails every time and shows an error

```
socket.io.min.js?v=1498289112:2 
GET https://www.xxxxx.com:30002/socket.io/?u=5&pathname=%2Fdashboard&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lx7Tlf8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Here is the requested headers

Provisional headers are shown

```
Origin:https://www.xxxx.com
Referer:https://www.xxxxx.com/dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; MotoG3 Build/MPIS24.107-55-2-17) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Here is my server.js code

```
var socket = require("socket.io");
var express = require("express");
var http = require('https');
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();

 var opts = {
 key : fs.readFileSync("/home/myhomedir/ssl/keys/9ca41_e1cd7_ece6805e7bdddf1ec6859d5cb27ab30f.key"),
 cert : fs.readFileSync("/home/myhomedir/ssl/certs/xxxx_9ca41_e1cd7_1529438222_b65b92c90fc0973371157d99ea679f4f.crt"),
 ca : [fs.readFileSync("gd.crt"), fs.readFileSync("g1.crt"), fs.readFileSync("g2.crt")],
 requestCert : true,
 rejectUnauthorized : false 
 };
 var server = http.createServer(opts, app);

app.set('trust proxy', true);
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your header you are connecting to your site with HTTPS but I don't see you inserting your certificate in the variable opts.

Shot in the wild but try this

Add your certificate privkey and cert to the folder you keep your server.js file in

Server side:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 8080;

http.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Client side:

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('https://yourwebsite.com:8080', { secure:true });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Tenasow recently I modified the question and placed my server.js code please take a look and help me please